# How to build angular 7 project using bazel

Tags: angular, bazel, angularbuild

I have angular 7 project, I need to do the production build of this in the bazel. The bazel is building other go langauage things, along with that i want a7 to be built.

NOTE : i want minimum changes to be done to my existing a7 project.

What is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the example here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/tree/stable/examples/angular

You shouldn't need to change the angular code it self just the build pipeline.